# Can we delimit a specific area to apply Subdivision?

Tags: modeling, displacement

As we can do with Procedural Displacement: we can use a B&W map to say: Only elevate this part of the object.
This would be great!

Comment: so I guess it's more like a request than a question?

Comment: I suppose I should infer that this is not available yet. That's too bad :(